# Codeigniter Fatal error: Call to a member function getMessage() on a non-object

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, codeigniter-3, paypal-rest-sdk

I am integrating PayPal Library with Codeigniter 3. When I first tried it worked well and I used test payment and gave me success but now, I am trying pay now button gives me error like this:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getMessage() on a non-object in 
C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\1\public_html\application\libraries\PayPal-PHP- 
SDK\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\sample\common.php on line 119
```

This is the Code of getMessage():

```
public static function printError($title, $objectName, $objectId = null, 
$request = null, $exception = null)
{
    $data = null;
    if ($exception instanceof \PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException) {
        $data = $exception->getData();
    }
    self::printOutput($title, $objectName, $objectId, $request, $data, 
   $exception->getMessage());
}
```

And here when I call ResultError in Contorller:

```
try {
        $payment->create($this->_api_context);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        // NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT USE RESULTPRINTER CLASS IN YOUR ORIGINAL CODE. FOR SAMPLE ONLY
          ResultPrinter::printError("Created Payment Using PayPal. Please visit the URL to Approve.", "Payment", null, $ex);
        exit(1);
    }
```

I searched a lot and found that they are saying there is something with null values and I changed them still no result. Please help me to solve this.